# How to freeze gridview column header in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, gridview

I need help on freezing gridview column header in asp.net.

I have tried to create a css code on page source code as displayed below:

```
 <style type="text/css">

    .Freezing
    {
        position:relative ;
        top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
        z-index: 10;
    }  

</style>
```

And after that i called the css into page load of web form.

```
  GridView1.CssClass = "Freezing"
```

Nothing happens whenever i debug the web application with above codes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should set the HeaderStyle css: `GridView1.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "Freezing"`

Comment: i tried it already but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You may using third party for database. Below are the url
http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this jquery plugin https://github.com/laertejjunior/freezeheader/

in your asp.net page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table").freezeHeader();

    });
</script>
```

if your page work with ajax, add this script in the end of page, to the script continue working after postback

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            $("table").freezeHeader();
        }
</script>
```

see demo in https://github.com/laertejjunior/freezeheader/

I hope this helps.